# htaccess 301 redirect to different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Trust me, I've searched all over for a solution to my problem, so I don't believe this is a duplicate question.

I need to do the following:

301 Redirect blog.example.com to blog.newexample.com.

What I have is close to working. When I go to the homepage of blog.example.com it will redirect perfectly to blog.newexample.com. However, if I go to blog.example.com/directory/page it does not direct me to blog.newexample.com/directory/page.

Here is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what your problem is, but this works just fine :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.newexample.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>
```

The URL `http://website.com/hello/world/` redirects me to 
`http://blog.newexample.com/hello/world/`.

Comment: I don't want to change website.com/hello/world. I want to change blog.website.com/hello/world to go to blog.newexample.com/hello/world. I basically just want to change the domain. The subdomain and paths need to stay the same.

Comment: Actually it was just to put a generic website URL, but I've tried on my own subdomain.domain.tld/somedir/hello/world, and it worked. And it should work on any domain and subdomain, such as yours.